# Convert criteria to detached criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

This question is titled similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35424717/581205), but it's no duplicate as the other OP actually wanted something else (anyway, there's no answer to my question there). What I want is to recycle my already constructed `Criteria` in `Subqueries.exists(DetachedCriteria)`.

I know that `Criteria` is basically `DetachedCriteria` with an attached `Session`, so I'd expect something like `Criteria#toDetached()` or a factory method on the other side, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per OP , it helped him to solve his problem.

One of the way could be the one given in [NHibernate: Convert an ICriteria to a DetachedCriteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753408/nhibernate-convert-an-icriteria-to-a-detachedcriteria) Thats for Nhibernate, but same can done in Hibernate Also.

Answer (score 2):

Trivially rewritten in Java:

```
public class MyDetachedCriteria extends DetachedCriteria {
    public OcDetachedCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        super((CriteriaImpl) criteria, criteria);
        ((CriteriaImpl) criteria).setSession(null);
    }
}
```